# Symfony 2 error: ....must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils in services.yml

Tags: php, symfony

I am passing an argument from services.yml to an authentication handler, and getting this error:

```
....must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils
```

This is the class:

```
class AuthenticationFailure extends DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
```

I have tried all of these but none work:

- @http_kernel
- @request
- @security.access.decision_manager
- @security.context
- @security.authentication.manager
- @security.secure_random
- @security.firewall
- @service_container

What am I missing?

So I just need to know what service do I pass that is an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils

Comment: show us the constructor, if you're injecting it via ctor. (surely in DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler` )

Comment: and a more complete error meesage.

Comment: No way do you need any of this information to answer this question

Comment: Answer is: @security_http_utils

Comment: you're f**g kidding me. No way I need information. Just answer yourself.

Comment: @security.http_utils

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
services:
    http.utils.class:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils
    security.authentication.your_success_handler:
        class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  [@http.utils.class, [], ...]
```